# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts to make a graph of payments made over time.

My configuration of AmCharts looks correct.

Also please note I am not a expert in Javascript.

Using AmCharts 3.18.3.free

The full console output is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseX' of undefined @ amcharts.js:4107
>       d.ChartCursor.d.Class.update @ amcharts.js:4107
>       e.AmRectangularChart.e.Class.update @ serial.js:346
>       e.AmSerialChart.e.Class.update @ serial.js:980
>       d.update @ amcharts.js:196

I'm also using [RainbowVis-JS](https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS).

```
newdata = [{"date":"2015-12-01T00:00:00-0600","Company 1":145,"Company 2":124},{"date":"2015-11-01T00:00:00-0600","Company 1":165,"Company 2":136}];
```

This entire item sits in a function that is called with jquery

User selects a company and clicks a button, which fires off this and pulls data.

This snippet is in the main body of the function that gets run. (mainFunc)

```
var that = this;
this.chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
```

The following is in the display function under the main function (mainFunc -> displayFunc)

```
newdata.reverse()
var companiesLength = companies.length;
var rainbow = new Rainbow();
rainbow.setSpectrum('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');
rainbow.setNumberRange(1, companiesLength); 
rainbow.colourAt(i);
var side = 'left'
var companiesLength = companies.length;
for (var i = 0; i < companiesLength; i++) {
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
    valueAxis.axisThickness = 2;
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 1;
    valueAxis.position = side;
    valueAxis.axisColor = rainbow.colourAt(i); // yields a specific html color
    that.chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    //graph.type = "serial";
    graph.bullet = "round";
    graph.fillAlphas = 0;
    graph.bulletBorderThickness = 1;
    graph.hideBulletsCount = 30;
    graph.valueField = companies[i]; // yields the name of the company
    graph.title = companies[i];
    graph.lineColor = rainbow.colourAt(i);
    that.chart.addGraph(graph);

    side = (side == 'left' ? 'right' : 'left');
}
that.chart.theme = "chalk";
that.chart.marginRight = 20;
that.chart.marginLeft = 20;
that.chart.autoMargins = false;
that.chart.dataProvider = newdata;
that.chart.categoryField = "date";
that.chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:NN:SS-0600";
that.chart.export = {"enabled": true, "position": "bottom-right"};

var categoryAxis = that.chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.parseDates = true;
categoryAxis.minPeriod = "MM";
categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.15;
categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";

var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
that.chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
legend.useGraphSettings = "center";
that.chart.addLegend(legend);
that.chart.addListener("dataUpdated", that.chart.zoomOut);
that.chart.write("chartdiv");
that.chart.zoomOut();
```

serial.js:346

```
this.chartCursor && this.chartCursor.update && this.chartCursor.update()
```

serial.js:980

```
e.AmSerialChart.base.update.call(this);
```

amcharts.js:196

```
c; c--) a[c].update && a[c].update(), b && (a[c].autoResize ? a[c].validateSize && a[c].validateSize() : a[c].premeasure && a[c].premeasure());
```

I'd like to add that I worked on this from looking into AmCharts code to try to backtrace why it was failing and couldn't find out why.

Here is the specific code section that it's complaining about, the middle line in particular

```
var a = this.chart,
    b = a.mouseX - this.x,
    c = a.mouseY - this.y;
```

Comment: I am loading serial and amcharts in the correct order.

Comment: I'm noticing a couple of irregularities with your chart: 1) you can `categoryField` set to "month", while the data has "date". 2) the data points are in reversed (descending order), they should be in ascending order. (you can use `newdata.reverse()` if you can't reorder your source data. Let me know if fixing the two above helps with the issue.

Comment: Noticed another: you have `graph.type = "serial"`. There is no such typo for graphs, which is confusing the chart. Remove this line altogether for default line graph type.

Comment: I have reverse newdata, I've commented out the graph.type, I got that from samples in makeChart type: serial. I've also corrected categoryField to be date ( i copied from samples). @martynasma I've also updated the question to reflect these changes.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. exact same error.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting the errors anymore: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/093893a409730a8a57d39e8b76da8343 Any chance of seeing your setup online? You can contact amcharts directly at contact@amcharts.com if you want to keep it private.

Comment: Ok, so from your working example I was able to fix that error. My div was missing the id which resulted in that error. However the codepen helped me out a lot to see what I was missing Thanks @martynasma!!

Comment: Awesome. It's always something very simple :) Glad that worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to answer my own question. @martynasma was a great help in helping to unconver why the code was not working.

Incorrect code:

```
<div class='chartdiv' >&nbsp;</div>
```

Corrected code:

```
<div class='chartdiv' id='chartdiv'>&nbsp;</div>
```