# AmCharts : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, typeerror

I am using AmCharts for stock related events. I am having following weird error in my console window.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseX' of undefined
    at b.followCursor (amcharts.js:271)
    at b.showBalloonReal (amcharts.js:130)
    at amcharts.js:130
```

My code is as follows:
-I use this function to fill data in dividendEventData variable.

```js
function getCompanyEventChartData() {
        var jqhx = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'marketID': '@Model.MarketID', 'companyID': '@Model.CompanyID' },
            url: "@Url.CompanyChartEvent()"
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i][1] == "31") {
                    var e0 = {
                        date: new Date(data[i][0]),
                        type: "sign",
                        backgroundColor: "#85CDE6",
                        graph: closeGraph,
                        text: "D",
                        description: "temporary",
                        url: "https://www.google.com/",
                        urlTarget: "_blank"
                    };
                    dividendEventData.push(e0);
                }
            }
        });
```

The dividendEventData is in this format.

```
[["Sunday, 18, Dec, 2016",31],["Thursday, 24, Dec, 2015",31],["Thursday, 11, Dec, 2014",31],["Thursday, 19, Dec, 2013",31],["Saturday, 22, Dec, 2012",31],["Saturday, 24, Dec, 2011",31],["Tuesday, 22, Feb, 2011",31],["Tuesday, 19, Jan, 2010",31],["Saturday, 29, Nov, 2008",31],["Wednesday, 20, Feb, 2008",31],["Tuesday, 27, Feb, 2007",31],["Monday, 28, Mar, 2005",31]]
```

I am then adding dividendEventData to my chart like this.

```js
simpleDataSet.stockEvents = dividendEventData;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#chartcurtain").hide();
                    chart.validateData();
                }, 1000);
```

My chart looks like this.
[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdZhM.png)

My chart works fine one time and display the description. But after next reload it does not show description when I hover my mouse over the events icon and it gives the error I mentioned earlier in console. I've deleted my cookies and have verified that the data returned from ajax call is same alway. I've followed [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516291/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-mousex-of-undefined) but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first initialize the chart, it expects data/config as JavaScript objects and arrays. It then proceeds to convert simple JS objects into instances of appropriate classes.

In case of Stock Events, it converts `stockEvents` array of objects into array of [`StockEvent`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockEvent) instances.

This is why your chart works the first time.

Now, when you are adding events to an already initialized chart, you're basically adding a basic object to `stockEvents` array. Now, when you do so, you end up with an array of mixed `StockEvent` instances and basic objects.

This time the objects are not converted into `StockEvent` instances, hence the anomaly.

What you need to do is to instantiate a new event as `StockEvent` and push that instance into `stockEvents` instead.

Something like this:

```
var e0 = new AmCharts.StockEvent();
e0.date = new Date(data[i][0]);
e0.type = "sign";
e0.backgroundColor = "#85CDE6";
e0.graph = closeGraph;
e0.text = "D";
e0.description = "temporary";
e0.url = "https://www.google.com/";
e0.urlTarget = "_blank";
dividendEventData.push(e0);
```

That should take care of it.

Here's a working example:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "theme": "light",

  "categoryAxesSettings": {
    "minPeriod": "mm"
  },

  "dataSets": [
    {
      "fieldMappings": [
        {
          "fromField": "value",
          "toField": "value"
        }
      ],
      "dataProvider": generateChartData(),
      "categoryField": "date"
    }
  ],

  "panels": [
    {
      "stockGraphs": [
        {
          "valueField": "value",
          "type": "smoothedLine"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true
  }
});

function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 1000);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setHours(0, i, 0, 0);

    var a = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;

    chartData.push({
      date: newDate,
      value: a
    });
  }
  return chartData;
}

function test() {
  var dividendEventData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    var e0 = new AmCharts.StockEvent();
    e0.date = new Date(chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider[r].date);
    e0.type = "sign";
    e0.backgroundColor = "#85CDE6";
    e0.graph = chart.panels[0].stockGraphs[0];
    e0.text = "D";
    e0.description = "temporary";
    e0.url = "https://www.google.com/";
    e0.urlTarget = "_blank";
    dividendEventData.push(e0);
  }
  chart.dataSets[0].stockEvents = dividendEventData;
  chart.validateData();
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="add event" onclick="test();" />
```

And here's the CodePen version of the same:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c37ef299206c6ab5a09c15b0f665e6f0?editors=0010

Comment: Please check the details of error and code in this > [Image](http://imgur.com/a/asbmx)

Comment: I have posted an update featured working demo. You'll see my code working fine there. (click "add event"). One thing to check is whether you are running the latest version of Stock Chart. (3.21.2) If you aren't, could you please try upgrading to see if that fixes the issue?